# angularjs routes and param and controller

Tags: angularjs

use url ~/list/result/1256

my code in one file

```
    App.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.when("/list/result/:param", {        
                        controller: "ListController"
                    });
                }]);


    App.controller("ListController", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "$http", function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) { 
    I want to get "1256"  here, but $routeParams - empty, why, what am I doing wrong
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the ListController is loading? Has you put a console.log in it?

Comment: Yes, the controller then loads the data on the page

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your question is incomplete. You have not posted the partial that loads when you navigate to the URL "/list/result/1256", i.e. your templateUrl is missing.
Secondly, you have not posted how you are trying to extract the param in ListController.

Per my knowledge,

```
var param = parseInt($routeParams['param'], 10);
```

should help you extract the param.